# isTraceEnabled needed or just trace is enough for logging

Tags: java, slf4j

My application runs on DEBUG log level, does this mean all of the following will be evaluated and trace will not be printed out.

or do I need to enable https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#isTraceEnabled-- before logging this snippet

```
    for (Element element : foreignMarkups) {
        log.trace("Foreign Markup name = {}", element.getName());
        log.trace("Foreign Markup value = {}", element.getText());
        log.trace("Foreign Markup namespace = {}", element.getNamespace());
    }
```

Comment: `isTraceEnabled()` is just for performance optimization.

Comment: yes, should I add so that the entire method gets stubbed out

Comment: https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance

Comment: It is important to note though that the method input is evaluated. Hence why its so crucial to use the loggers formatter instead of formatting the string urself. So if you would write `log.trace("Result: " + result)`, this string concatenation is computed. `isTraceEnabled` is used to guard expensive logger calls. for example if u have `log.trace("...", expensiveMethod())`, the only way to ensure that u dont pay the price when trace is disabled, is to guard it with `if (log.isTraceEnabled()) { log.trace(...); }`.

Comment: I can’t tell whether you’re asking about optimization, or just asking whether log statements which use the trace level will be seen when the logger’s level is set to debug.  The answer to your first sentence is yes, that is indeed what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Java cannot magically sniff that this code is going to end up doing nothing. It'll be run - that for loop is going to invoke `foreignMarkups.iterator()`, so an interator will be made (an object is instantiated, but its small, and fast garbage soon after), and this code will loop through every element, fetching pointers to the various strings that those 3 get methods are pointing at.

None of that is particularly expensive, but, if `foreignMarkups` has more than, say, 1000 or so elements, it'll take non-instant time at that point.

If you actually want this code to just be skipped entirely, and not incur those relatively small costs as outlined above, you have 2 options:

### avoid string concat

Specifically to avoid the cost of string concat, you do this:

```
log.trace("Hey there {} {}", firstName, lastName);
```

and not:

```
log.trace("Hey there " + firstName + " " + lastName);
```

Because string concat is non-trivial (at the very least, it means a new string is created with the full content), and the logging framework will simply not concatenate the parts together if trace isn't enabled. In the second snippet, java will generate the code to do it, which will concatenate the string (with all costs associated with this), and then send it to the log framework which then immediately ignores it as trace isn't enabled.

### Lambdas

You can pass lambdas to `log.trace` and friends instead of values; the lambdas will be invoked **only** if needed, i.e. only if that log level is relevant:

Do this:

```
log.trace("Hey, {}", () -> makePriceyDbCallToLookupFirstName(obj));
```

not:

```
log.trace("Hey, {}", makePriceyDbCallToLookupFirstName(obj));
```

### isXEnabled

None of the previous 2 plans seem particularly relevant for you. You can use the lambda trick, but only if you compress your 3 log.trace outs into a single log.trace, and the lambda calculates the entire string. You can do that. Or just use the final fallback, `isXEnabled`. Do this:

```
if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
  log.trace(priceLookup1());
  log.trace(priceLookup2());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the application runs at Debug log level nothing at trace level will be logged.